# Able to View Table in Databricks with whe DESCRIBE function/method but unable view the Data with REFRESH

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

When I execute the Databricks method 'DESCRIBE' on table I'm unable to view the table. However, executing the REFRESH method produces the folloiwng error:

```
REFRESH TABLE retail.managers

Error in SQL statement: SecurityException: User cannot SELECT on table `retail`.`managers` because:
--The owner of table `retail`.`codeproduct` is different from the owner of table `retail`.`managers`

DESCRIBE retail.managers
```

[image]

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error?
I should mention the tables aren't listed in our Catalog Explorer. Which is  why I'm surprised the `DESCRIBE retail.managers` produces the table in the first place.

Comment: Is the table manged table or exteranl table?

Comment: Hi @DileeprajnarayanThumula, thanks for getting in touch. I believe it's an external table. Why do you ask?

Comment: As you said you cant see the tables are not listed in catalog explorer

Comment: In the Catalog explorer there are PERMISSIONS where you can grant
Check the privileges you would like to grant.

ALL
gives all privileges

SELECT
gives read access to an object

MODIFY
gives ability to add, delete, and modify data to or from an object

READ_METADATA
gives ability to view an object and its metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates a security exception,
That the user cannot `SELECT` on the **retail.managers** table because the owner of the **retail.codeproduct** table is different from the owner of the **retail.managers** table.

- This error occours when the user lacks ownership and proper
  permissions for the involved tables.

As you mentioned you cannot see the tables  listed in catalog explorer. If you are using the databricks manged tables
By default, managed tables are stored in **/user/hive/warehouse** in Hive warehouse.
You can grant permission like below

**Manged Tables:**
A managed table in Spark SQL is a table where Spark takes care of both the data and metadata.
Now, a global managed table is a special type of table that is accessible across all clusters.
When you delete or drop this table, both the actual data and the metadata are removed entirely.

For example I have used Hive_metastore catalog in databricks.
I have enabled the `spark.databricks.acl.sqlOnly true`
In the cluster configuration like below:
[image]
Using the above command it allows to grant permission on the table
[image]

You can select the user and grant the permissions for default hive_metastore manged tables

[image]

As per databricks if you want your table to appear in you default catalog,you can create a Default catalog for the workspace:

[image]

***Note: This setting only applies to Unity Catalog compatible compute i.e. when the workspace has an assigned Unity Catalog metastore, and the cluster is in access mode 'Shared' or 'Single User', or in SQL warehouses.***